# Asymmetric encryption in python with cryptography module retunes blank file

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to recursively encrypt files with asymmetric encryption but the files returns blank after decryption. Key gen, opening the key files, and shredding the old files seems to work fine.

Here is the key gen program which is working fine. it generates the keys and saves them to 2 files:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(public_exponent=65537, key_size=2048, backend=default_backend())
public_key = private_key.public_key()
pem = private_key.private_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM, format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8, encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption())
print(pem)
with open('private_key.pem', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pem)
pem = public_key.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM, format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo)
print(pem)
with open('public_key.pem', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pem)
```

Here is the encryption program. It loads the keys then loops recursively using glob. It then encrypts the files line by line writing to new file, and shreds the old file:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
import glob
import os
import random

def getKey():
    with open("public_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
        public_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(key_file.read(), backend=default_backend())
    return(public_key)
def shred(filePath):
    f = open(filePath, 'r')
    length = 0
    for i in f:
        length = length + 1
    f.close()
    f = open(filePath, 'w')
    for i in range(0, length):
        f.write(str(random.getrandbits(1024)))
    f.close()
    os.remove(filePath)
curDir = os.getcwd()
public_key = getKey()
print('begining encryption')
for x in glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\code\\python\Deimos\\encrypt\\**\*', recursive=True):
    fullPath = os.path.join(curDir, x)
    fullNewF = os.path.join(curDir, x + '.aes')
    if os.path.isfile(fullPath):
            fileList = []
            f = open(fullPath, 'r')
            for i in f:
                fileList.append(i)
            f.close()
            encryptedFileList = []
            for i in range(0, len(fileList)):
                encryptedFileList.append(
                    public_key.encrypt(
                        fileList[i].encode(),
                        padding.OAEP(
                            mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
                            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
                            label=None
                        )
                    )
                )
            f = open(fullNewF, 'w')
            for i in range(0, len(encryptedFileList)):
                f.write(str(encryptedFileList[i]))
            f.close()
            shred(fullPath)
```

Here is the decryption program. It opens the key file, loops recursively using glob, then decrypts the file line by line writing encrypted text to the new file, then shreds the old file.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
import glob
import os
import random
def getKey():
    with open("private_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            key_file.read(),
            password=None,
            backend=default_backend()
        )
    return(private_key)
def shred(filePath):
    f = open(filePath, 'r')
    length = 0
    for i in f:
        length = length + 1
    f.close()
    f = open(filePath, 'w')
    for i in range(0, length):
        f.write(random.urandom(1024))
    f.close()
    os.remove(filePath)
curDir = os.getcwd()
private_key = getKey()
print('begining decryption')
for x in glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\code\\python\Deimos\\encrypt\\**\*', recursive=True):
    fullPath = os.path.join(curDir, x)
    fullNewF = os.path.join(curDir, x.strip('.aes'))
    if (fullPath[-4:] == '.aes'):
            fileList = []
            f = open(fullPath, 'r')
            for i in f:
                fileList.append(i)
            f.close()
            decryptedFileList = []
            for i in range(0, len(fileList)):
                decryptedFileList.append(
                    private_key.decrypt(
                        fileList[i],
                        padding.OAEP(
                            mgf=padding.MGF1(
                                algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
                            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
                            label=None
                        )
                    )
                )
            f = open(fullNewF, 'w')
            for i in range(0, len(decryptedFileList)):
                f.write(decryptedFileList[i].decode())
            f.close()
            shred(fullPath)
```

Comment: I didn't read the whole code by I was immediately struck by your `shred()` method. It expands the file to be shredded  by more than a factor of 300 before deleting it. Also, there are methods in `os` and `pathlib` to obtain the length of a file without having to read it character by character. See any of the `stat` methods for example.

Comment: Thankyou, I'll look into that

Answer (score 0):

readline() method does not work for what ever reason but readlines() works insted.